# How to open downloaded file from local database in dart?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How to open downloaded file from local database in dart ? openfile.open(String filepath) does work for new android versions.

Comment: Hi,
You can use downloads_path_provider package, to access the download directory. For more information please see the documentation: https://pub.dev/packages/downloads_path_provider
Best Regards,

Comment: I have used path provider but it doesn't work in MI Note 7 and another version of MI phones. I am able to download but I am not able to open that file in MI phones.Even this function openfile.open(String filepath)   supports in lenovo phone older versions.Is there any other please suggest.